# getting an a error when I try to populate text boxes based on combo box selection

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Trying to get text boxes to populate when a name is selected from my combo box (cboCo). Getting the error `method range of object'_worksheet' failed` on fourth line of code.

I am not a strong programmer and VB has always been a struggle for me. I am working on creating a form for a vendor spreadsheet that will allow users to view data in the spreadsheet, edit vendor data, add new data and delete data as needed. I so far have got it to add data and show the company names in the combo box. What I am working on currently is getting the text boxes to populate with the data in the row for the company selected in the combobox.

```
Private Sub cboCo_Change()
  Dim iRow As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("VendorInfo")
  LastRow = ws.Range(1 & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row

  For iRow = 2 To LastRow
    If (Me.cboCo.Value) = ws.Cells(iRow, 1) Then
      Me.cboCat = ws.Cells(iRow, 19).Value
      Me.cboCat = ws.Cells(iRow, 19).Value
      Me.cboYrApprv = ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value
      Me.txtContact = ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
      Me.txtPhone = ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value
      Me.txtEmail = ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
      Me.txtCoAdd = ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value
      Me.txtWebSite = ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value
      Me.txtAccred = ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value
      Me.txtStanding = ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value
      Me.txtSince = ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value
      Me.txtNotes = ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value
      Me.txtVerified = ws.Cells(iRow, 12).Value
      Me.txtToday = ws.Cells(iRow, 13).Value
      Me.txtServProd = ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value
      Me.txtApprvBy = ws.Cells(iRow, 15).Value
      Me.txtAprvReas = ws.Cells(iRow, 16).Value
      Me.txtOrder = ws.Cells(iRow, 17).Value
      Me.txtPurchs = ws.Cells(iRow, 18).Value
    End If
  Next iRow
End Sub
```

When I select a company from my cboCo combo box I get the `method range of object'_worksheet' failed` error on the fourth Line (starting with LastRow just above my loop)

Comment: (You have an extra `Me.cboCat = ws.Cells(iRow, 19).Value` that you could remove).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Range()` incorrectly.  Try this:

```
LastRow = ws.Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

or

```
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Originally, it was resolving to basically `ws.Range(1 & 1048576)...` --> `ws.Range(11048576).End(xlUp).Row`, which A) isn't a proper `Range` and B) is a non-existent row number.

Also, note it's `xlUp`, not `x1Up` (it's an "L", not a "1")

Comment: Thanks, I put the letter l to make sure it had not made a mistake and tried the code given. Now it tells me "Application-defined or object-defined error" when I select a company from the combo box (highlights the same line)

Comment: LastRow = ws.Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: If it helps, my combobox draws its data from a list on a separate page in the work book. the form should take the information in the drop down box and find it in the sheet from which the list is derived and populate the rest of the text boxes with the appropriate cell information. Here is the code I used for the drop down boxes.

Comment: ''making the dropdown boxes
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim cCoList As Range
    
     Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")
       
   ' show companies in the drop down box
    For Each cCoList In ws.Range("CoList")
    With Me.cboCo
        .AddItem cCoList.Value
     End With
    Next cCoList

Comment: @bcgeogirl that might be a separate question. The issue of lastrow has been fixed so I'd start a new question.

Comment: Maybe there is just a better way to do this?