# Text boxes not populating when selection is made in combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form that adds data to a spreadsheet. In it is a combo box that shows companies already added to the spreadsheet. i am trying to create code to populate the text boxes.

This is for a vendor spreadsheet to make it easier for people to find, edit, delete and add vendors. I have created the form and code for the Add button, and populating the three comboboxes. These comboboxes derive their data from lists in a separate sheet in the workbook where I have defined the lists. I have been attempting to populate the form's text boxes with the data in the row that matches the company selected in the combobox. I have been playing around with the fourth line of code tyring to get it to form a range from which to look for the company names on the sheet with all the company data. I have had a number of different errors, this is the first code that did not give an error but it does not do anything either.

```
Private Sub cboCo_Change()
    Dim iRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheet3
    LastRow = ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(300, 1)).End(xlUp).Row
    'LastRow = ws1.Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        'I changed sheets("VendorList") to ws1 so wherever you see ws1 was previously sheets("VendorList")
        If Sheet3.Cells(i, "A").Value = (Me.cboCo) Then
           Me.txtContact = ws1.Cells(i, "B")
           Me.txtPhone = ws1.Cells(i, "C")
           Me.txtEmail = ws1.Cells(i, "D")
           Me.txtCoAdd = ws1.Cells(i, "E")
           Me.txtWebSite = ws1.Cells(i, "F")
           Me.txtServProd = ws1.Cells(i, "G")
           Me.txtAccred = ws1.Cells(i, "H")
           Me.txtStanding = ws1.Cells(i, "I")
           Me.txtSince = ws1.Cells(i, "J")
           Me.txtNotes = ws1.Cells(i, "K")
           Me.txtVerified = ws1.Cells(i, "L")
           Me.txtToday = ws1.Cells(i, "M")
           Me.cboYrApprv = ws1.Cells(i, "N")
           Me.txtApprvBy = ws1.Cells(i, "O")
           Me.txtAprvReas = ws1.Cells(i, "P")
           Me.txtOrder = ws1.Cells(i, "Q")
           Me.txtPurchs = Sheets("VendorList").Cells(i, "R")
           Me.cboCat = Sheets("VendorList").Cells(i, "S")
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

It should look at the name in the combo box, find the name in the worksheet and then put the text from the row into the corresponding text boxes but it does not do anything. I do not get an error either.

Comment: sheet3 is most likely your culprit. You should fully qualify it by doing "Thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet3")"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting an a error when I try to populate text boxes based on combo box selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258430/getting-an-a-error-when-i-try-to-populate-text-boxes-based-on-combo-box-selectio)

Comment: Avoid the loop and use `Range.Find`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the loop all together. Use the `Range.Find` method to search for your value in `Me.cboCo`. If your value is found, we will populate your text boxes with the row.

You can amend the options on the `.Find` method to optimize the search. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

---

```
Private Sub cboCo_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim Found As Range, i As Long

Set Found = ws.Range("A:A").Find(Me.cboCo)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
  i = Found.Row
    Me.txtContact = ws.Cells(i, "B")
    Me.txtPhone = ws.Cells(i, "C")
    Me.txtEmail = ws.Cells(i, "D")
    Me.txtCoAdd = ws.Cells(i, "E")
    Me.txtWebSite = ws.Cells(i, "F")
    Me.txtServProd = ws.Cells(i, "G")
    Me.txtAccred = ws.Cells(i, "H")
    Me.txtStanding = ws.Cells(i, "I")
    Me.txtSince = ws.Cells(i, "J")
    Me.txtNotes = ws.Cells(i, "K")
    Me.txtVerified = ws.Cells(i, "L")
    Me.txtToday = ws.Cells(i, "M")
    Me.cboYrApprv = ws.Cells(i, "N")
    Me.txtApprvBy = ws.Cells(i, "O")
    Me.txtAprvReas = ws.Cells(i, "P")
    Me.txtOrder = ws.Cells(i, "Q")
    Me.txtPurchs = Sheets("VendorList").Cells(i, "R")
    Me.cboCat = Sheets("VendorList").Cells(i, "S")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this did work! Now I just have to figure out formatting as it looks funny in the text boxes :)

Comment: @bcgeogirl please accept the solution (check mark to left of answer) since this solved your issue in your original question:)

Answer (score 0):

Here try this and see if it solves your issue. This code basically does the same thing but working in memory instead of interacting with the object(s) too much.

```
Private Sub cboCo_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    dim arr as variant
    arr=thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr,1)
        If arr(i, 1) = Me.cboCo.value Then
           Me.txtContact = arr(i, 2)
           Me.txtPhone = arr(i, 3)
           Me.txtEmail = arr(i, 4)
           Me.txtCoAdd = arr(i, 5)
           Me.txtWebSite = arr(i, 6)
           Me.txtServProd = arr(i, 7)
           Me.txtAccred = arr(i, 8)
           Me.txtStanding = arr(i, 9)
           Me.txtSince = arr(i, 10)
           Me.txtNotes = arr(i, 11)
           Me.txtVerified = arr(i, 12)
           Me.txtToday = arr(i, 13)
           Me.cboYrApprv =arr(i, 14)
           Me.txtApprvBy = arr(i, 15)
           Me.txtAprvReas = arr(i, 16)
           Me.txtOrder = arr(i, 17)
           Me.txtPurchs = arr(i, 18)
           Me.cboCat = arr(i, 19)
        End If
    Next i
    FormName.Repaint
End Sub
```